# grep -E (not working) vs grep -Po (working)

Tags: regex, shell, grep, pcre

I have shell script for ci cd pipeline. I am executing it in intellij ide terminal.

```
latestVersionAvailable=$(curl -s $artifactoryPath/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)'$VERSION'.*?(?=</version>)' | sort -V | tail -1)
echo " latest $latestVersionAvailable"
```

when I use above it inside shell script, it is working with -Po , but when I use -E it is not giving me any results back why?

Comment: What does the doc (`man grep`) say about the `-P` and `-E` options you used?

Answer (score 2):

`-E` is for extended regular expressions. Unlike PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions, `-P`), ERE don't support look ahead assertions.